# Is there a way to remove this unresponsive window of Action Center program in windows 7 without a restart?

Tags: windows, windows-7

The following window is not disappearing at all. I don't want to do a restart or shutdown. Also, It persists even after a sleep.

My issue is a persistent Aero window that wouldn't close. nothing related to backup.

How to remove it ? is there some process or service I can kill ?

A small window of action center program is stuck:

[image]

Comment: @spikey_richie It worked fine. Many thanks! you can answer the question and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @spikey_richie If you are willing, You can make a detailed answer and explain why this works and how explorer.exe is related to that window.

Comment: @harrymc i think the question is a little different in this case. The user seems to have a persistent Aero window that can't be closed.

Comment: @spikey_richie: If the answers in the linked post do not help the poster, he may edit his post with more information and ask to reopen it (the edit itself will supposedly place his post on the reopen queue).

Comment: @harrymc I don't think the question is duplicate. It's completely different.  Nothing in the other question would help me. so, I will edit and repost.

Comment: I reopened it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This window/tile will be 'hosted' by the `explorer.exe` process.

I would suggest the following actions:

1. Open up Task Manager
2. Find `explorer.exe`
3. End Task on `explorer.exe`
4. From the File menu in Task Manager, select `Run new task`
5. Enter `explorer.exe` and click OK

These steps will restart the explorer process, and the windows it's hosting.